# Show that by means of the transformation $w=\frac 1z$ the circle $C$ given by $|z-3|=5$ is mapped into the circle $|w+\frac{3}{16}|=\frac{5}{16}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value, conformal-geometry

> Show that by means of the transformation $w=\frac 1z$ the circle C given by $|z-3|=5$ is mapped into the circle $\left|w+\frac{3}{16}\right|=\frac{5}{16}$

**My try:**
$$\begin{align}\\
&w=\frac 1z\\
&\implies 3w=\frac 3z\\
&\implies1-3w=1-\frac 3z=\frac{z-3}{z}\\
&\implies|1-3w|=\left|\frac{z-3}{z}\right|\\
&\implies|1-3w|=|z-3|\left|\frac 1z\right|\\
&\implies|1-3w|=5|w|\\
\end{align}\\$$
But, I can't understand what to do next and how can I proof that. Any suggestions? or, you can add an answer.

Comment: A circle is determined by three points; try finding the image of several points and reconstructing the circle.

Comment: The symmetry wrt the real axis is preserved, so $[w(-2), w(8)]$ is a diameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|z-3|=5.$$
Let $\displaystyle w= \frac{1}{z}$ and let $w^\star$ be the conjugate of $w$.

$$\begin{aligned} 
\left(\frac{1}{w} -3 \right) \left(\frac{1}{w^\star} -3 \right) &= 25 \\
(1 -3 w^\star) \left( 1 - 3w \right) &= 25 w w^\star\\
1-3(w+w^\star) + 9 w w^\star &= 25 w w^\star \\
16 w w^\star + 3(w + w^\star) -1 &= 0\\
w w^\star + \frac{3}{16} (w + w^\star) &= \frac{1}{16}\\
\left( w + \frac{3}{16}\right) \left( w^\star + \frac{3}{16} \right) &= \frac{9}{16^2} + \frac{1}{16} = \left( \frac{5}{16}\right)^2\\
\left| w + \frac{3}{16} \right| &= \frac{5}{16}.
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Wow, awesome 

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that if $|z-3|=5$ so $$\left|\frac{1}{z}+\frac{3}{16}\right|=\frac{5}{16}.$$
Let $z=x+yi,$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Thus, $$(x-3)^2+y^2=25$$ and we need to prove that:
$$|3z+16|=5|z|$$ or
$$(3x+16)^2+9y^2=25(x^2+y^2)$$ or
$$16(x^2+y^2)=96x+256$$ or
$$x^2-6x+y^2=16$$ or
$$(x-3)^2+y^2=25$$ and we are done!

Comment: Can you please tell why you proved this with inequality?

Comment: I think it's wrong..under inverse transformation a circle maps to a circle ,not to a disk.We are not asked to prove the statement you have written in the first line of your post.

Comment: Yes I see now. It was my mistake, but the idea of the solution is true. I fixed. Thanks all!

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}{}{}{}$